# getting no shipping and payment method in cart and checkout page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I am getting error on console in magento 2.3 on cart and checkout page, by which i cannot see any shipping and payment method

I upgraded magento from 2.2.1 to 2.3.3 before its working fine after upgrading its giving me issue

Error on console

```
jquery-2.2.2.min.js:4 GET http://www.testing.projectblitz.com/m232/checkout/undefinedcustomer/section/load?sections=cart&force_new_section_timestamp=false&_=1579163223222 404 (Not Found)

customer-data.js:95 Uncaught Error: [object Object]
    at Object.<anonymous> (customer-data.js:95)

jquery-2.2.2.min.js:4 POST http://www.testing.projectblitz.com/m232/checkout/undefinedrest/default/V1/carts/mine/estimate-shipping-methods 404 (Not Found)
jquery-2.2.2.min.js:4 POST http://www.testing.projectblitz.com/m232/checkout/undefinedrest/default/V1/carts/mine/totals-information 404 (Not Found)
```

Screenshot:  https://www.screencast.com/t/SnBYDVJ4

But its working fine on luma theme, its something issue with my custom theme, how can i debug this or correct this.

I am also cannot see items on my mini cart

Comment: Debug more in var/log.

Comment: Nothing in log.